# Add custom user control on pivot selection change

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uno-platform

I have Pivot with a custom user control in it.

```
 <Pivot.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local1:mycustomusercontrol></local1:mycustomusercontrol>
                </DataTemplate>
  </Pivot.ItemTemplate>
```

Now on the selected item change on Pivot I want my `mycustomusercontrol` to be replaced with another user control. Is there a way to achieve this?

```
  private void PivotContainer_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PivotContainer.SelectedIndex != 0)
        {
           //Change user control
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIElement` has the property `Children` which contains all the child elements it contains, you could perhaps try to change that.

However, personally I would prefer to use a `DataTemplateSelector` and inside of that define the logic of which `DataTemplate` to show based on some criteria on the ViewModel displayed on that position.

Alternatively if `DataTemplateSelector` doesn't do it for you, you could define both states in your `mycustomusercontrol` and toggle visibility for them.

Lots of solutions to your problem.

Comment: Can you please show me any link where I can see DataTemplateSelector for this purpose?

Comment: Are you using Xamarin.Forms or plain UWP?

Comment: Plain UWP. Actually on UNO platform

Comment: How about actually tagging UNO in your question then? Docs for DataTemplateSelector for UWP can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.datatemplateselector

Comment: Yes, Done so. Menwhile Datatemplate can't be repeated inside a Pivot.ItemTemplate so, this won't be working for me